# (How) can I make a decorator narrow a type in the function body?

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I am implementing a decorator to replace repeated early-exit checks such as

```py
if self.data is None:
    self.log_something()
    return
```

at the top of my methods. This approach (highly simplified here) does work nicely:

```py
"""early exit decorator."""
from collections.abc import Callable

Method = Callable[["Class"], None]
Condition = Callable[["Class"], bool]

def early_exit_if(condition: Condition) -> Callable[[Method], Method]:
    def decorator(method: Method) -> Method:
        def wrapper(instance: "Class") -> None:
            if condition(instance):
                return
            method(instance)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

class Class:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.data: list[int] | None = None

    @staticmethod
    def data_is_none(instance: "Class") -> bool:
        return instance.data is None

    @early_exit_if(data_is_none)
    def do_something_with_data(self) -> None:
        self.data.append(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Class().do_something_with_data()
```

In short, `@early_exit_if(data_is_none)` ensures that `data` is not `None` in the body of `do_something_with_data`. However, `mypy` does not know that:

> bug.py:30: error: Item "None" of "list[int] | None" has no attribute "append"  [union-attr]

How can I let `mypy` know (ideally, from within the decorator) that `data` is not `None`?

I know that `assert self.data is not None` works, but I dislike duplicating the check.

*Edit*: I just learned about `TypeGuard`s, and I wonder if this approach can be combined with decorators.

Comment: This comment appears on most such questions - have you considered adapting a Builder pattern here? If `data` is populated somewhere in the middle of `Class` lifecycle, you can return a `StrictClass` from a method where this happens, and do not allow `None` in `StrictClass` value.

Comment: `TypeGuard` won't narrow function argument types: the body is checked against signature as written, and decorator transform is applied only to the signature independently.

Comment: The decorator is a *dynamic* effect; a static typechecker won't "apply" it while type checking your original function, so it has no idea that `None.append` can't be called.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you may already have the best answer:

```
assert self.data is not None
```

Is well documented by [mypy in type narrowing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html?highlight=assert) among other things.

Remember that it doesn't necessarily duplicate the check as *assert* is meant to be use mostly at development time, in production you can run "python -O" (optimized mode) and asserts are just ignored, so it doesn't impact performance at all.

Comment: Good point! It still duplicates the code for the check, though, making it error-prone to maintain in the future...